# Language switcher duplicate parameters

Tags: error, store-view, magento-2.2.1

I have two store view **"en"** for english and **"ar"** for arabic. When i click english store view icon, the url gets changed to

> "https://my-magento-store.com/?__store=en"

and after that when i click arabic store view icon, the url gets changed to

> "https://my-magento-store.com/?__store=en&__store=ar"

and returns **error page**. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What about if you refresh the page then you click first on the arabic icon ? what will be the URL

Comment: Hi, @PЯINCƏ , i tried that now, but no use, the store code get appending to the url each time i click language switch icon, looks like "https://my-magento-store.com/?__store=en&__store=ar&__store=en&__store=ar"